# How to pass props from html div to the function component in react?

Tags: reactjs

Don't know how to pass properties from html into react file.
This is the existing code,

```
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="mydiv" parm="some info"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="h2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The react file, i'm manually sending props "parm={2}" for now.

```
const Hello = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        return (<h2>h2 with function component {props.parm}</h2>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello parm={2} />, document.getElementById('mydiv'));
```

My Q is, how to pass parm from html to Hello() component ?
Pls note, i have to turn off CORS for local testing,
https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: This is not how React is designed to work. `ReactDOM.render(..., document.getElementById('mydiv'))` is going to **replace** the contents of the `div` that has `id` of `mydiv`, with your React components. Why do you want to do this in the first place? What is your use case? This also has nothing to do with CORS. I suggest reading some React docs, or following a React tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible.

Note: I'm not sure what your use-case is. Maybe you are "[sprinking](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)" react into an existing project? If you are not, I'd suggest you take a look at the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) as they might suggest a better way to achieve your outcome.

Anyway, here's an example that implements what you have asked. Notice your HTML param is logged to the console. You can then use it inside react.

https://codesandbox.io/s/params-to-react-from-html-lycqx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
// here's how to get the value itself
const myParam = document
    .querySelector("#my_container") // get the html element, e.g. a div
    .getAttribute("myParam"); // get the value of the custom property on that element
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to pass myParam into LikeButton() directly ? so LikeButton(props) should be LikeButton(domContainer), here domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");

Answer (score 0):

React is not designed to behave in that way, HTML div you are using is the root element and all component is going to render in that. so you can not pass. but in first place why you want to do that. there are other ways to use global values inside of react component.

Not ideal solution but you can use global scope to get the value inside, or else create separate service to store values and then import that inside react component.

Comment: Hello is my function component, I want to have a way to manual test and unit test this component. I’m new to reactjs, so still doing research.